# Why is this python code slower than the php version?

Tags: php, python

I've always heard Python was faster than PHP, especially for math operations, so I am quite surprised at the performance of this Python code. What gives?

Python:

```
iterations = 1000000
x = [i for i in range(iterations)]
y = [i*i for i in range(iterations)]

def integrate(x, y):
    total = 0
    size = len(x)
    for i in range(1, size):
        total += (x[i] - x[i-1]) * .5*(y[i] + y[i-1])
    return total

for i in range(100):
    integrate(x, y)
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$x = [];
$y = [];
$iterations = 1000000;

for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++)
{
    $x[] = $i;
    $y[] = $i * $i;
}

function integrate(array $x, array $y)
{
    $sum = 0;
    $size = count($x);
    for($i = 1; $i < $size; $i++)
    {
        $sum += ($x[$i] - $x[$i-1]) * ($y[$i] + $y[$i-1])/2;
    }

    return $sum;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    integrate($x, $y);  
}
```

Comment: Two code snippets are not identical.

Comment: @ozgur: Yes. Furthermore useless variables (size), differences in multiplying… But, what's the problem? If you want something very fast, goto coding in C, or C++!

Comment: @ozgur Can you point out where the main speed difference is coming from? Although the code is not identical, the Python one should still be faster.

Comment: @EdwardYu which python version are you using?

Comment: As per the results [here](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/) PHP is usually slightly faster compared to Python. I made some changes to the script to remove the unnecessary list creation(use `xrange()` in Python 2)  and now it takes **31** seconds(earlier it was **37**) on my system compared to PHP's **26**. OTOH if you really want speed consider using [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), takes just **.95** second.

Comment: @ozgur I am using Python 3.4

Comment: For Python 3.4, replace `itertools.izip` with `zip` in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, in Python, everything is an object.  `for i in range(1, size)` creates a million objects for every test, and if you're using Python 2, it does so before it even starts processing, blowing out your cache as well.  I don't do PHP and have no idea what kind of speed hit you're seeing, but this version of integrate is 25% faster than your Python version on my machine using Python 2.7:

```
def integrate(x, y):
    total = 0
    x, y = iter(x), iter(y)
    x0 = next(x)
    y0 = next(y)
    for x1, y1 in itertools.izip(x, y):
        total += (x1 - x0) * (y1 + y0) * 0.5
        x0 = x1
        y0 = y1
    return total
```

Of course, one of the *main* reasons that Python is considered to be faster is all the easily downloadable libraries for it.  For this task you should almost certainly be using something like numpy rather than straight Python.

Because, again, *everything* in Python is an object, and integers are immutable objects.  Even the line `total += (x1 - x0) * (y1 + y0) * 0.5` will create and destroy 5 objects every time you execute it:  create x1 - x0, create y1 + y0, create the product, destroy the first two objects, create the divided by two object, destroy the product, create the new total, destroy the old total and the divided by two object.

That's a lot of work that I don't believe the PHP interpreter is doing, so this is exactly the sort of benchmark that will make PHP look good relative to Python.